# What is the difference between jquery, Modenizr and innerShiv

Tags: jquery

I have been using jquery for quite a while.  I see people talking about Modenizr and innerShiv but I am not able to figure out exactly what each does and if there is compatiblity issue between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is a library that is dedicated to making it easier to create logic and interactions in JavaScript. Modernizer and innerShiv are components that solve specific problems with UI interactions; it's a bit like comparing apples (jQuery) and ford F-150s (Modernizr / innerShiv).

There should be no compatibility issue.

Comment: [This document](http://jdbartlett.github.com/innershiv/) addresses innerShiv and jQuery, while providing a great overview of innerShiv.

Comment: +1 for comparing an a software application to an F-150, it doesn't make any sense to me, but I work for Ford.  Sticking with quasi-automotive terms, I would say it's more like comparing duck tape (jQuery), a radar gun (Modernizr), and a mechanic (innerShiv)